Native LockCanvas error in lockCanvas. Tell me how to fix it. please
I'm doing lockCanvas on the surface I received via idl from another app, but the error below appears. It's already lockedCanvas, so I don't think there's an error. There's no logic like that.
If you know any of these cases, please let me know the solution. Thank you
04-16 12:06:24.401 21416 21416 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
04-16 12:06:24.401 21416 21416 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
04-16 12:06:24.401 21416 21416 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:405)


It's not accurate, it's a guess. It seems like the error above occurs when one app tries to lock/unlock in another after locking/unlock in Surface. I solved this error by creating a new Surface and locking/unlocking it in different Surfaces.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
